# Inheritance design for having similar entities but with different properties

Tags: c#, oop, architecture

I'm designing a several views, which should show a list of players and their properties, but from different perspectives.

```
ViewA shows player's: Name, Exp, Skill, Condition
ViewB shows player's: Name, Exp, Skill, Bonus
ViewC shows player's: Name, Exp, Price, Bid amount
```

Common thing for all views are `Name` and `Exp` - so there's a sense to move them to the BaseView. Also, there's a `Skill`, which is used in 2/3 views and will be probably used in some next views, so it also can be moved to the base view.

The questions are:

- If to have all properties rendering in the BaseView and to use them in particular views - wouldn't it violate OOD?
- If to make new BaseWithSkillView (which would obviously inherit BaseView and implement `Skill` property rendering) - wouldn't it be an unnecessary entity?
- (rhetorical question) If to keep `Name` and `Exp` in a BaseView and re-implement `Skill` property in ViewA and ViewB - wouldn't it be a code copying.

What are the recommended practices for this case?

UPD: To make question more generic, assume i have 20 properties and 10 Views, each of them should show, say, 7 different properties. I'm afraid i'll end up with BaseWithSkillExpHpManaBonusView.

Comment: BaseView, => BaseWithSkill, => ViewA, ViewB; BaseView => ViewC

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for answer, i had updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 20 properties and 10 Views and each of them should show ~7 different properties, I would recommend you to use decorator pattern.

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/designpatterns/VRQT130713-Decorator-Design-Pattern---C

In this case you would have smth like IBaseView, BaseView, BaseViewDecorator, HealthDecorator : BaseViewDecorator and so on.

Comment: Yea, its sounds like an option